# Nginx redirect based on user agent version

Tags: redirect, nginx, user-agent

I have a custom user-agent and I would like to do a redirect if the version of client is less than required.

```
  location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ Foo) {
     return 301 https://somewhere.else
   }
  }
```

How to add version check here? For example criteria could be less than version 4. So Foo/3.3 should redirect but Foo/4.0 should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Foo/([1-2]\.|3\.[0-3])
```

Which matches: `Foo/1.`, `Foo/2.`, `Foo/3.0`, `Foo/3.1`, `Foo/3.2`, and `Foo/3.3`